# Julia: my computer crashes when I use Mmap.mmap

Tags: julia, mmap

I try to use `X = Mmap.mmap(io, Vector{Float64}, (10^9,))` , but does not finish creating the array, the computer crashes, then i need restart the computer, although `X = Mmap.mmap(io, Vector{Float64}, (10^8,))` finish creating the array without any problem.  Is there any way to fix this?

- I used a text file to store the array.
- I use Julia 0.5.0
- processor: INTEL: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz, 6037 MB
- GPU: NVIDIA : GeForce GT 630M, 2048 MB
- OS: Windows10, x64

Comment: mhmm ... a better way would have been to edit your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46189027), especially since there are no answers on it.

Comment: sorry, I'm not yet fully familiar with the forum

Comment: Regarding, the other question, you may want to just `open` a file for writing, and `seek` 10^9 bytes ahead and write something. This automatically extends the file to this size and pads with zeros the skipped bytes. You don't have to use Mmap for handling binary files. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/io-network.html